# Accessing model data in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am using the below lines to pass data to my template index.html, model1 being the class in my models.py.

```
     data = model1.objects.all()
     return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', {'data': data})
```

I am able to access data on the front end by using a for loop as shown below

```
 {% for x in data %}
   <h3>{{x.name}}</h3>
   <h4>{{x.department}}</h4>
 {% endfor %}
```

Since there are mutliple objects in this data, my question is if I want to access only the department of particular object with certain name, how can I do that?

For example here I am using a for loop, consider there are two objects in the data. Then the output would be

```
name1
department1
name2
department2
```

So now if I need to access only name2 without any loop, how can i do that?

**Updating the question**: I am updating this question with html, so that the question looks clear.

```
table id="example" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>View/Edit</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for x in data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.department}}</td>
    <td>View</td>
  <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  view</button></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

This is how my html looks, I am using data-table here. So all the data is captured in a table automatically. As you can see every row has a view button that I would implement. Once the user clicks the view button, I should pop up a modal dialog to show all the other details like {{x.dateJoined}} etc which I don't show in the table. But if I use a separate view to pop this dialog, I should send a request to the view from my template saying which row(with some ID) the user has clicked. How can i achieve that? How can I bind the view button with respective rows here?

Comment: `x.name` & `x.department` will render as it is, you mean `{{ x.name }}` & `{{ x.department }}`?

Comment: thats my mistake, i edited the question. There are many objects in the data right, each object has its own name and department. How can I access a name from a particular department I need?

Comment: Sorry! But your question is still vague, what you mean by `How can I access a name from a particular department I need?` please provide example.

Comment: question updated. please check. thank you

Comment: You only want single object in template and not all objects? why don't you then filter in view and only send single object in context? Or you want all objects in template and still want to pick particualr object from queryset within template?

Comment: yes, I want all the objects in template but I would like to use them wherever I want independently. Actually I am displaying all the data in a data-table . But once a user clicks a particular row, he should one see the respective objects data populated in a modal window..

Comment: You then need to create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) (probably [assignment_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.assignment_tag) if Django<=1.8 or [simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) if Django >= 1.9) which will take the queryset and filtering parameters and returns you appropriate object. Are you familiar with the templatetags?

Comment: I am new to django, can you provide me an example here as a solution for my case?

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: Django version 1.11.2

Comment: How well do you know javascript?

Comment: I can call myself an intermediate

Comment: See my answer.  The solution is to have two views.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write custom template tag which will take the queryset and filtering parameters and returns you appropriate object, you can use [simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag):

**myapp/templatetags/myapp_tags.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def get_model1_object(queryset, **filters):
    if not filters:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError('`get_model1_object` tag requires filters.')
    retrun queryset.filter(**filters).first()
```

Then in template:

```
{% load get_model1_object from myapp_tags %}

{% get_model1_object data name='blah' as obj %}
```

***Note***: Your filtering criteria might yield multiple results but in `get_model1_object` i am only returning the first object assuming your criteria will be strict, change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that template rendering happens on the server, before the user sees anything in their browser.  The template is not sent to the user, only the HTML that the template generated.  When the user is interacting with the page, the original template is not involved.  So, you have two choices here:

1. You can render the data for all the objects in hidden div's on your page, then use javascript with something like a jquery dialog to display them on demand.  This is only realistic if you have very few records.
2. You can create a second view with its own template, which renders just the HTML for the modal dialog contents.  You could then, again using javascript/jquery, make an AJAX request to load the contents of the dialog that you need when you need it.  In your first view template, the list of departments, include the url of the object you want to fetch, eg:

   ```
   {% for x in data %}
   <tr>
   <td>{{x.name}}</td>
   <td><a class="deptlink" href="{% url 'dept_detail' x.pk %}">
       {{ x.department }}</a></td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Where dept_detail is the name of the urls.py entry for your view that supplies the contents of the dialog.

Then in your javascript, hook the `a` tag so it opens your dialog instead of leaving the page:

```
     $('.deptlink').click(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         # then the code after this is up to you, but something that'll
         # load the url into your dialog and open it.
         $('yourdialog').load($(event.target).attr('href'));
```

Since you say you are an intermediate in javascript I won't get into the details of implementation, but basically, the moral of the story is that the output of django is going to be an HTML page.  Anything that you need to have on the client side either has to be in that page, or you will have to make another request to the server to get it...  Either way, you'll need some javascript to do this, since you want a modal dialog with client side interaction.

Comment: I am using a data-table to showcase all the data, but the data-table doesn't show all the contents in particular object. It only shows few important information. But once an user clicks view button for each row, the full contents are shown. Now if I invoke a modal dialog using a separate view, I believe I should set a filter in my view depending on what the user clicks. How can I implement this? Now if the user clicks a row of an object with ID 1, I should show the name and department of the object with ID=1 in a modal dialog. But how can I pass the info from front end to backend here?

Comment: Since I only used datatables once I am not an expert.  In my answer I show you how (in your template) to create a url string which contains the id (pk) of the selected row in it.  You could put this link into the datatable as an anchor as I have shown.  Or you could put that url in a data property of the table row and then fetch it using javascript in various ways depending on how you make your clickable element in your html/javascript.

Comment: What I am saying is, for EACH row in your datatable you will have a different object therefore a different link will be generated.  However are you asking how to pass a url parameter to a django view?  That's a different problem.

Comment: How can I fetch the ID for each row here? Also please check the updated part of the question. Thank you.

Comment: what does x.department.pk mean in your code? How can i change this pk value for each row, since I am writing code for a row only once using for loop.

Comment: Since you say there is detail information for each department I assumed that department was a ForeignKeyField to another model.

Comment: No, its a single table in the DB. But my requirement only allows me show certain data in the data-table. All other data is shown in the modal dialog. I have an idea, I am not sure if it works. What if I serialize the model data into JSON and then send it to the template. Since the data is in JSON format now I can easily access it right?  Can I by any chance do this?

Comment: Yes that's basically similar to my first suggestion.  Django offers a json serializer for models, or you can just use the regular python json library to convert the fields you want into json.  You'd do this in your view and add it to the render context so you could use it in your template.

Comment: Actually the easy way to accomplish that would be to add a method to your model class which returns the desired json as a string, then you can just do {{ x.get_json }} in your template

Comment: Can I use {{}} format for json data in my template? Could you provide me an example here?

Comment: Any variable in your template rendering context will be put into the output as text using {{ variable }}.. but there are some escaping rules.  It's beyond my ability to explain in a comment.. see the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/